# Riemann integral notation

Tags: integration, notation

I came across many notations for a Riemann integral of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$, such as $$\int_{[a,b]} f,~~~~ \int_a^b f,~~~~\int_a^b f(x)~dx$$
Where does this multitude come from? Should I stick to one of these notation or avoid some of them?

Comment: If you don't have a name for the function $f$ but you do have an expression in $x$ for the value of the function when its argument is $x$, then you should definitely included $dx$. For example, $\displaystyle \int_A e^{-xy}\arctan x\,dx$ and $ \displaystyle \int_A e^{-xy}\arctan x\,dy$ are two different things. $\qquad$

Comment: One often omits the $dx$-part due to laziness and to save energy by not typing it in, especially when it's implicitly understood w.r.t. which variable we're integrating. The main thing about the first integral is that we explicitly state the set $[a,b]$ over which we are integrating, which fits better with the more general framework of integration theory, where one considers integration of functions over arbitrary sets (circles, $\mathbb{R}^d$, blobs…). You then write $\int_A f(x) dx$ to denote that you're integrating over the set $A$. Depending on the scenario, each of your examples will…

Comment: …work, but there are also cases (like in integration theory courses) where you might also have to state what measure you're using, like for example $\int_A f(x)\lambda(dx)$, where $\lambda$ stands for the Lebesgue measure, or $\int_Af(x)\delta(dx)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac measure. You might even have to denote your limits by introducing a suitable characteristic function, like $\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}\chi_A(x)f(x)\lambda(dx)$.